# errorhandler not firing when DEBUG is False

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I'm using [errorhandlers](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/errorpages/#error-handlers) to catch and handle certain kinds of exceptions:

```
@app.errorhandler(CustomException)
def handle_custom_exception(error):
    return redirect('redirect-path', code=301)
```

This works correctly when `DEBUG` is `True`, which implicitly sets `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` to `True` as well. When `DEBUG` is `False` though, `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` defaults to `False` and Flask returns a `500` for all errors thrown, ignoring the registered `errorhandler`s. Setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` to `True` corrects the error handling in this case.

What i'm wondering about is:

- Is it safe to have `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` enabled in production? Are there any side effects I should be concerned about?
- Why does Flask have different default values for this config in debug vs non-debug?

Answer (score 2):

You should add 
`app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True`
It happens because flask overrides the usual error handling code (for all routes under its control).

Comment: This does not answer "Is it safe to have `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS` enabled in production?"